# Batch convert flv to mkv with mkvmerge

Tags: batch, batch-file, matroska

I have a bunch of *.flv videos in a folder on my Windows computer that I would like to convert (or remux) to *.mkv. Since I have a lot of files I would like to automate this process with a batch script using mkvmerge.

To find the proper syntax I used the command line display in MKVmergeGUI and I got the following:

> "D:/OneDrive/Portable applications/mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe"
>   ^"--ui-language^" ^"en^" ^"--output^"
>   ^"C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test/Episode 01.mkv^" ^"--language^"
>   ^"0:und^" ^"--default-track^" ^"0:yes^" ^"--language^" ^"1:und^"
>   ^"--default-track^" ^"1:yes^" ^"--language^" ^"2:nor^"
>   ^"--track-name^" ^"2:Norwegian subtitles^" ^"--default-track^"
>   ^"2:yes^" ( ^"C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test/Episode 01.flv^" )
>   ^"--track-order^" ^"0:0,0:1,0:2^"

However these commands are not relative. I want all flv's in a folder to convert to mkv. I simply need a batch file that can remux from flv to mkv. How can I achieve this using only a batch file and mkvmerge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out an adequate solution using the following command in a batch file:

```
for %%A IN (*.flv) do ( mkvmerge.exe -o "remux-%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A")
```

This will convert the flv to mkv and name the output remux-*filename*